# how to change time format in csv into hh:mm:ss

Tags: r, datetime

This is my time series data :

```
Date                Time    Price
05/03/2018  09:00:00am  125.9
05/03/2018  09:00:00am  125.9
05/03/2018  09:00:00am  125.9
05/03/2018  09:00:00am  125.9
05/03/2018  09:00:00am  125.9
```

I want to change my time format into "hh:mm:ss" for 24 hours systems, and I want my output like this

```
NewDate            Price
05-03-2018 09:00:00 125.9
05-03-2018 09:00:00 125.9
05-03-2018 09:00:00 125.9
05-03-2018 09:00:00 125.9
05-03-2018 09:00:00 125.9
```

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See an example below, you can change the timezone `tz` to whatever it should be.

```
date <- "05/03/2018  09:00:00am"
as.POSIXct(date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", tz = "UTC")
```

`%p` is the AM/PM indicator in the locale. A good place to look for documentation is the details sections of `?strptime`.

Answer (score 1):

The `lubridate` package makes it easy:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(NewDate = lubridate::mdy_hms(paste(Date, Time))) %>%
  select(NewDate, Price)

              NewDate Price
1 2018-05-03 09:00:00 125.9
2 2018-05-03 09:00:00 125.9
3 2018-05-03 09:00:00 125.9
4 2018-05-03 09:00:00 125.9
5 2018-05-03 09:00:00 125.9
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("05/03/2018", "05/03/2018", "05/03/2018", 
"05/03/2018", "05/03/2018"), Time = c("09:00:00am", "09:00:00am", 
"09:00:00am", "09:00:00am", "09:00:00am"), Price = c(125.9, 125.9, 
125.9, 125.9, 125.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```